# Strange characters in Django shell, arrowkeys not working

Tags: python, django, shell, ipython

After doing nothing out of ordinary, my shell from Django is broken

```
    (virtulenv)miki@blablabla >>  python manage.py shell
    Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
    Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

    IPython 2.3.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
    ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
    %quickref -> Quick reference.
    help      -> Python's own help system.
    object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

    In [1]:
```

It displays the signs for white space as these special chars, but as I look at the preview here, it's not displaying, I'm putting here a image of it...
[image: wrong prompt]

However, that is not he only problem. The arrows and history is not working

`In [1]: ^[[A^[[B^[[D^[[C`

This happens in the plain shell as well:

```
    (virtulenv)miki@blablabla >>  python manage.py shell --plain
    Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
    [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    (InteractiveConsole)
    >>> ^[[A^[[B^[[D^[[C
```

I've tried installing readline and recompiling python.

Ideas?

Comment: did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I did, actually...

My boss had added this to settings, when removed it's fixed...


    sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
    sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)

Comment: it is not really good idea to remove them. I had these added also on top of my settings file so my console prints out the unicode chars without errors. check out my answer tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out...

Boss added this to settings, which causes it, because of encoding on production. I added the condition and set the enviroment variable on my computer and it's fixed...

```
if not os.environ.get("DISABLE_UTF8_REDEFINE"):
    sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
    sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 4):

After suffering from the same issue for long time [I found out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#shell) that installing [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) or [ipython](http://ipython.org/) did not only solve the problem, but also made my debugging-life much easier with their syntax highlighting, auto indentation, suggestions autocomplete and many other fancy stuff.

simply install bpython

```
pip install bpython
```

or ipython

```
pip install ipython
```

I personally recommend bpython over ipython as it is much lighter and just what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal is broken. The current value of `$TERM`, assuming there is one, does not match the terminal in use.

Comment: Make sure the value of `$TERM` is appropriate for your terminal.

Comment: I have a different virtualenv, where the command line works fine and the $TERM value is the same in both virtualenvs...

Comment: Then something somewhere is changing it.